# Why does my arraylist stay empty despite adding objects?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method that factorizes the number n into the product of primes. For example factorizing 12 would result in 3 x 2^2. The first block of code factorizes n into loose numbers so 12 = 3 x 2 x 2 and places them in f. The second block is then supposed to store these numbers in p as powers instead of loose numbers by counting the exponent as the amount of times a number occurs in f, so 3^1 x 2^2 instead of 3 x 2 x 2. This is done with an object Power which stores the base and exponent of a number.

For some reason however, this code keeps returning empty arrays. And after looking it over many times I still have no idea why this would be the case. Is there something I'm doing wrong or that I misunderstand?

```
/**
 * factorize n
 *
 * @param n the number to 'powerize'
 * @modifies none
 * @pre {@code 2 <= n}
 * @return factorization of n
 */
public static List<Power> factorize(int n) {
    List<Integer> f = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // f are factors
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            f.add(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }


    List<Power> p = new ArrayList<Power>(); // p are the factors with powers
    for (int j = 2; j <= n; j++) { //j will be the base
        int e = 0; //exponent
        for (int k = 0; k <= f.size(); k++) {
            if (f.get(k) == j) {
                e++;
            }
        }
        p.add(new Power(j, e));
    }

    return p; //returns factors in powered form
}
```

I'll add the code for the Power object in case it's necessary.

```
/**
 * Record containing a base and an exponent.
 *
 * @inv {@code 0 <= base && 0 <= exponent}
 */
public static class Power { // BEGIN RECORD TYPE

    /**
     * The base.
     */
    public int base;

    /**
     * The exponent.
     */
    public int exponent;

    /**
     * Constructs a Power with given base and exponent.
     *
     * @param base the base
     * @param exponent the exponent
     * @pre {@code 0 <= base && 0 <= exponent}
     * @post {@code \result.base == base && \result.exponent == exponent}
     */
    public Power(int base, int exponent) {
        this.base = base;
        this.exponent = exponent;
    }

} // END RECORD TYPE
```

Comment: Did you step it through in a debugger?

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? If yes, what is the smallest number where your program does not work correctly?

Comment: Debugger would've shown that immediately: after the first loop `n=1` as it's fully factorized out. So, your second loop performs zero iterations.

Comment: @yeputons And that's also why there is no ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ... `for (int k = 0; k **<=** f.size(); k++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you debug you will see that your `n` variable value is `1` after first `for` cycle. That's why second cycle not started at all